# xml file is not accessible

Tags: java, api, rest, jakarta-ee

I am creating some REST APIs. For this I have some  application level common name value pairs. To configure those name value pairs , I just created an xml file in WebContent and accessed values from the xml in a static block of a class and initialized with static variables. So all values which are given for each name in xml will be assigned to respective static variable from a class's static block.

I am able to access those variables and get values in each classes other than from a REST API client. The problem comes, when I'm creating a REST API client for consuming API's created in the same project, FileNotFoundException is throwing for the path I have given for my xml file(WebContent/myxml.xml).

I can see that, its searching for the same xml file in my eclipse path(/home/aneesh/eclipse/WebContent/myxml.xml). And FileNotFoundException throwing.
    How can I resolve this issue?

```
1. class which accessing xml file
class Constants {
   public static String name;
   static {
        initializeConstants();
    }
public static void initializeConstants() {
     try {
     //initializing Constants
     //"Reading file"
     File xmlFile = new File("WebContent/myxml.xml");
     .......
     //file is getting read perfectly and "name" is initialized 
      }
}
2. class accepting static variable Constants.name
   // accepting value of 'name' using Constants.name successfully
   // writing a method which is accepting some parameters and using Constants.name.
   // writing a "main" method and calling this class's methods will work perfectly.
   // value of Constants.name will be accessible here.

3. REST API created which will call methods of second class with parameters.

4. Webscript client created for consuming above created API.
   // Here the exception is coming.
   // Eception is throwing from the class Constants
   //Exception from Constants : FileNotFoundException
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aneesh/eclipse/eclipse/WebContent/myxml.xml (No such file or directory)
```

So, why in this case its looking for the file in eclipse's path? How to resolve it?
    Tried by putting into src folder also, but not working.

Comment: Please add some code. Most likely the FileNotFoundException occurs because there really is no file. Check for your absolute and relative paths once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the path as WebContent//myxml.xml
(Note the double forward slashes //)

Comment: How do forward slashes change the outcome?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please read
The answer given by you is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the path of the XML file dynamically.

You can use ServletContext object's getRealPath() - you can use it like : getRealPath("/"), which returns you the path of the application deployed. Then from there you can navigate to the XML file required inside your application.

ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();

String path = context.getRealPath("/");

Use the variable path and navigate to your XML.

Answer (score 0):

As I my class is not a Servlet class; I followed;

```
public  String getAppPath() {
        java.net.URL r = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myxml.xml");
        String filePath = r.getFile();
        String result = new File(new File(new File(filePath).getParent()).getParent()).getParent();

        if (!filePath.contains("WEB-INF")) {
            // Assume we need to add the "WebContent" folder if using Jetty.
            result = FilenameUtils.concat(result, "WebContent");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: But its throwing java.lang.NullPointerException at line "String filePath = r.getFile();" some times. Can any one fix this for me pls?

Comment: Keeping copy of resource file (myxml.xml) in src folder solved the issue.